# How can I share my clipboard between two Macs?

Tags: macos, clipboard

Is there an easy way I could send clipboard data from one Mac on the LAN to another?

Answer (score 10):

You can't do this with built-in methods, of course. I've researched a bit and here are the results I could find:

#### Simple clipboard sharing for OS X

There are a couple of simple tools that claim to do this.

- [ClipCommControl](http://www.derman.com/ClipCommControl) is freeware and has support for 10.4 and 10.5, 10.6 and above untested.
- [Stuf](http://www.theescapers.com/stuf/index.html) is a Windows/Mac clipboard manager that also synchronizes between machines. It offers a free 30 day trial. Seems like a more recent app that is also under active development.
- [ClipboardSharing](http://lagercrantz.ath.cx/software/clipboardsharing/) is rather old, and was written at the time of OS X 10.3. However, it seems to run and install on 10.6 too. It's freeware.
- [ClipboardMultiSharer](http://clipboardmshare.steweche.co.uk/) is Java based, therefore works on a few platforms, but isn't that pretty. It's also free.

Here is an article from 2009 that mentions a couple [clipboard managers for OS X](http://gigaom.com/apple/10-clipboard-managers-for-os-x/), of which only Stuf is mentioned as having the capabilities you look for.

#### Synergy

If you're up to something more sophisticated, a program like [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/), free and open source. It allows you to switch between different machines at the same time, and as a bonus, it also shares your clipboard with those.

Might be a bit over the top for just clipboard sharing, but it's something worth taking a look at if you control multiple machines at the same time.

Comment: an anonymous user provided this info: I tried ClipCommControl on 10.6.8 as a standard user and it won't get past the splash screen .    ClipCommControl  10.6 doesn't work (at least if you are not an admin on your mac) 10.7/10.8 untested, but unlikely to work if 10.6 doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

[Teleport](http://abyssoft.com/software/teleport/), a virtual KVM switch, includes an option to synchronize the clipboards.  It installs as a pref-pane on each computer.  I use it regularly between an iMac and a Macbook.

Comment: Very cool. Is a great replacement for VNC also.

Answer (score 1):

Clipboard sharing is built into the OS X screen sharing application.

Answer (score 0):

Synergy 2 allows for keyboard/mouse sharing across multiple platforms

http://synergy-foss.org/

Answer (score 0):

[**Command-C**](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/command-c-clipboard-sharing/id692787282?mt=12) is another app via AppStore. Actually this app is to share clipboards with iOS (to and from iOS devices) on the same network, but in the FAQ page the developper writes you can share clipboards with another Mac as well.